# lambda expressions on populated lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

There are a few posts on the site about how to order by using lambda expressions however I cannot seem to get mine to work. I am trying to reorder a list that is already populated. Am i wrong in thinking that i can rearrange the order of this list using lambada expressions?

```
QuarterMileTimes.OrderByDescending(c => c.PquartermileTime);
```

I was wondering if it's down to PquartermileTime being a string? I also tried this expression on a date

```
QuarterMileTimes.orderBy(c => c.RaceDay);
```

Still no luck where am I going wrong?

Comment: lambada is the forbidden dance. I think you want lambda..

Comment: @Jeff Atwood:  You haven't seen all the new features of C# 4.0 yet eh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx), the method returns a **new** `IEnumerable<T>` - it does not reorder the collection in place.

Try doing:

```
QuarterMileTimes = QuarterMileTimes.OrderByDescending(c => c.PquartermileTime).ToList();
```

(This is if your collection is a `List<T>`...)

Answer (score 1):

The result of `OrderByDescending` (and all of the other `Enumerable` extension methods) is an `IEnumerable<T>` that projects the source data in the order you're describing. It does *not* alter the original data in any way.

If you prefer, you can use the `ToList()` extension method to create a new `List<T>` from that result and assign it back to the original variable.

```
QuarterMileTimes = QuarterMileTimes.OrderByDescending(/*...*/).ToList();
```

(This is assuming, of course, that `QuarterMileTimes` is a `List<T>`)

The gist of the answer is **no**, `OrderByDescending` does not alter the data source in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning it to a new variable aren't you?

```
var sortedTimes = QuarterMileTimes.OrderByDescending(c => c.PquartermileTime);
```

It isn't like e.g. the List.Sort method, that sorts the existing list.
The result of the method has to be assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

OrderByDescending returns an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` i.e. a new sequence with the items in the specified order. You'll have to re-assign QuarterMileTimes to get the behaviour you expect:

`QuarterMileTimes = QuarterMileTimes.OrderByDescending(c => c.PquarterMileTime).ToList();`

Alternatively you can just use the returned sequence separately, which is the usual approach.

Answer (score 0):

`QuarterMileTimes.OrderByDescending(c => c.PquartermileTime)` returns a new enumerable, ordered by `PquartermileTime`. It does not reorder `QuarterMileTimes` in place.